# Object with static methods vs object methods -> which is more effecient?

Tags: coldfusion, lucee

In Lucee / Coldfusion, if I have an object that doesn't do anything in an init() nor has properties, and all that it has are helper functions, which of the following two would be more efficient performance / memory wise, and why please?

```java
// public object based function
var rsData = new foo.bar.Object().getList();
```

vs

```java
// public static function
var rsData = foo.bar.Object::getList();
```

I've been debating this and am not sure of the answer.

Comment: For performance, run each one 100 times in a loop and see which one is quicker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a "begging the question" situation.

Performance ought not be a consideration here, as the difference will be negligible. If you haven't even written the first iteration of the code yet, and don't yet have a performance-bound situation to address: this is a case of premature optimisation.

If the CFC is a library rather than the representation of an object: use class (static) methods. If it's a representation of an object: use object methods. That's what you ought to be reasoning. Not some (entirely perceived, at this point) performance consideration.

Bear in mind that for testing purposes, inline method calls - which static methods lend themselves more to - are not possible to bypass (eg: via mocking / stubbing / doubling), so one ought to be... circumspect... about the static method's usage. If it's purely algorithmic so performant and has no side effects, then this is not an issue. This is often not the case as poorly planned/organic code evolves. Also bear in mind that a static reference (`MyClass::myStaticMethod`) is a hard-coded dependency, and innately increases the complexity of the code it is within.

These are the sorts of considerations one ought to be making before using static method calls. Not performance.

Intrinsically, that said, static method invocation requires the class to be loaded *once* for the lifetime of the app, whereas an object method has overhead of the object being created. That kinda goes without saying though.

Comment: Thank you Adam It's that last paragraph of yours that got me wondering, regarding "...static method invocation requires the class to be loaded once for the lifetime of the app....". Got be wondering memory wise what was better to do.. even though I (kinda) know the GC is there to clean up as things are marked at "disposable" kinda thing.

Comment: Yeah I'd say that's the sort of thing to only start worrying about if it becomes something that needs worrying about. In the meantime, write the code that's clearest  most appropriate to the situation from the perspective of people maintaining the code. Remember that the target audience of code is "humans" not "computers".